# Use of 'Open'-command for counting lines and chars from file in Python

Tags: python

For an assignment I have to count the characters and lines of a file. I came up with the following idea:

```
ascii_file = open('ascii.txt')
num_lines  = sum(1 for line in ascii_file)
num_char   = len(ascii_file.read())
```

But this returns 0 for the num_char value. Why is this happening?
The solution I found was quite simple though:

```
ascii_file = 'ascii.txt'
num_lines  = sum(1 for line in open(ascii_file))
num_char   = len(open(ascii_file).read())
```

But I'm still curious why the first script isn't working properly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file object `ascii_file` iterator is exhausted after the first iteration `sum(1 for line in ascii_file)`.

You would need to use `ascii_file.seek(0)` to go back to the start of the file and then do `num_char = len(ascii_file.read())`  or use `ascii_file = open('ascii.txt').read()` storing all the lines in the variable `ascii__file` .

In your second example you are opening the file twice so you are not iterating over the same file object.

On a side note you should use with to open your files as it will close them automatically:

```
with open('ascii.txt') as ascii_file:
    ...
```

An example:

```
In [32]: f = iter([1,2,3])

In [33]: for line in f: # first iteration prints 1,2,3
            print(line)
   ....:     
1
2
3

In [34]: for line in f: # no output as iterator is exhausted
            print(line)
   ....:
```

Comment: You could add `file_obj.seek(0)` to your answer.

Comment: @Padraic, just to add another potential solution, using `itertools.tee` would also be a very elegant solution, although not potentially slower in this case than using `read ` to keep the file in memory.

Comment: @RafaelLerm, True, just wanted to keep it simple though and explain how an iterator works.

Answer (score 1):

**Calculate Number of Lines In a File**

```
ascii_file=open("ascii.txt",'r')
num_lines=len(ascii_file.readlines())
num_char=len(ascii_file.read())
ascii_file.close()
```